# "There is a need for a lot of patience" vs "It takes a lot of patience"

Tags: sentence-choice

Are both sentences fine? As I see it on the internet, the second version is used more common among English natives. On the other hand, a phrase "there is a need" also is used, as I understand it. Maybe not in this context?

> **There is a need** a lot of patient to get one’s goal.
>
> **It takes** a lot of patient to get one’s goal.

Comment: Neither are correct, so the examples you have seen on the internet must be wrong.

Comment: I believe you meant to say 'patience' instead of 'patient'?

Comment: Observe, using a dictionary, the difference between 'patience' (noun) and 'patient' (adjective).

Comment: @Michael, OP should also note the difference between "patient" (noun) and "patient" (adjective).

Comment: @Dhanishtha Ghosh, yes, it is. Thank you for polite communication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Astralbee observes, the examples that you have seen on the internet cannot be from native speakers because they are wrong. Of course you may have transcribed them incorrectly.

Here are correct versions. I have highlighted the needed corrections.

> There is a need **for** a lot of **patience** to get **to** one’s goal

> It takes a lot of **patience** to get **to** one’s goal

both mean the same thing although the first strikes me as a somewhat stilted version of

> A lot of patience is needed to reach your goals.

Comment: Why is it necessary to use "to" after verb "get"? Could you answer, please?

Comment: Because the obvious meaning here of "get" is "succeed" or "reach," which is an intransitive use that cannot take a direct object.

Comment: So, in this case it's possible to replace "get to" with "reach", isn't it? It takes a lot of patience to **reach one’s goal**.

Comment: @Sergey Absolutely correct.

Answer (score 1):

Those are two **incorrect** usages of the word "patient".  For the first example it would be more correct to say:

> "There is a need for a lot of patience to get one's goal."

For the second example, you might say:

> "It takes a lot of patience to get one's goal."

Both mean essentially the same thing.  The second example is probably more common in everyday language in the USA at least.

If you prefer to use the word "patient" instead of "patience" an example might be:

> "You must be patient while working toward your goal."

Comment: Not sure you're right about "one's" versus "ones".  https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26327/is-the-possessive-of-one-spelled-ones-or-ones  http://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/apostrophe/possessives

Comment: Granted I've seen it both ways.  I was taught as above.

Comment: Hmm, I've never heard of the possessive of "one" being "ones" without an apostrophe. Not saying that no one teaches that, but I'm 62 years old and a native speaker and I've never heard it. This page, https://brians.wsu.edu/2016/05/19/ones-ones/ says the appropriate possessive is "one's". And this page https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/one's lists a bunch of idioms from Merriam-Webster involving the possessive of "one", and in every case they use an apostrophe.